# URL dont want to open - Not allowed

Tags: html, limesurvey

in the question in LimeSurvey software in survey I have a link to a path on the disk,

and when I click it, it won't open. If it copies the link to a new window, it opens.

Code:

```
<a href="G:\IT">MIPA</a>
```

G:\IT - is in server, everyone in company has access

error

> Not allowed to load local resource: 
> index.php?r=survey/index&sid=164918:345

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///G:/IT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents loaded over HTTP(S) are **not allowed** to link to local documents on the user's hard disk for security reasons. Hence the error.

The only work-around is to move `file:///G:/IT` to an HTTP(S) URL.